# Use image file on other server as Icon of webkitnotifications

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-notifications, webkit-notifications

I'm making a Chrome Extension.

I want to use a image file on other servers as an icon of webkitnotifications(Desktop notifications)

**in Content Script**

```
window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
    "http://www.example.com/icon48.png", "title", "text"
).show();
```

**in manifest.json**

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "notifications", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
]
```

but I got the following error

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

The URL of the icon changes in many ways. So I cannot add all of them to "web_accessible_resources" in manifest.json beforehand.
So, how can I do the above ??
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my extension, with Chrome 23, I can point to **external icon url** like this without any problem

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
    'http://placehold.it/48x48',  // no need to add to "web_accessible_resources" beforehand
    title,  // notification title
    textToDisplay // notification body text
);
```

Comment: thank you so much!
I found your code works well on Windows.
On Mac OSX, it doesn't work. I guess Mac's notification system use the icon of the application...